# add field to database without erasing data of table in Prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm, prisma

i'm trying to use Prisma ORM.
in my table some data exists and this is my model:

```
model User {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id 
  username String @db.VarChar(100) @unique
}
model Post {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt  DateTime   @default(now())
  title      String
}
```

in user model exists some data. how can i add 'password' field in User model without delete any data from User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line to the User model and it worked.

```
password String ?
```

the ? means that this field can be blank or null.